# for each loop around blade @sections is it possible

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have been learning "code" just over a year for a project i have and have got stuck on a particular function that i am trying to create for the user. I have lots of divs with different information being rendered from a database. Html and css looks great I have then created blade @sections to hold the info but struggling to add functionality.

```
@foreach($canal as $canal)
    @section('water-left')
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/canals/' . $canal->image)}}">
            @section('location')
                <strong class="words myh4">{{$canal->name}}</strong>
                    @section('water-right')
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/canals/' . $canal->image)}}">
                    @endsection
            @endsection
    @endsection
@endforeach
```

I have paginated contents of database to 3 and am trying to attatch the id1 image to ('water-left'), the id2 name to ('location') and id3 image to('water-right') currently i get just id1 in all sections any help please my controller looks like this

```
public function getcanalimage()
{
    $canal = Canal::paginate(3);
    return view('waters.canal_fishing',compact('canal'));
}
```

any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: If $canal is an array you must insert loop foreach with blade

Answer (score 0):

Try to use foreach loop, because $canal is array with more one values and you need use a loop to show all them:

```
@section('water-right')              
@foreach($canal as $item) 
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/canals/' . $item->image)}}">
    @endforeach 
@endsection
```

Comment: Hi Diego thanks for the response  this has the same affect as the above coding, but i am trying to increment each section by 1 i cant paginate as normal because my html has other divs and section's mixed in different locations all over the page . is there an answer to this or will i have create a public function in the controller for individual sections and then add some java script.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since the question was posted but, for anyone using Laravel 5.8, there seems to be an undocumented [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade) *tag/directive* called **@overwrite**.

So replacing **@endsection** with **@overwrite** should do the work.

```php
@foreach($canal as $item)
    @section('water-left')
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/canals/' . $canal->image)}}">
            @section('location')
                <strong class="words myh4">{{$item->name}}</strong>
                    @section('water-right')
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/canals/' . $item->image)}}">
                    @overwrite
            @overwrite
    @overwrite
@endforeach
```